# IP Restrictions are not allowing the use of Google Sheets SF Add-On Data connector for Salesforce

Tags: google, google-apps, ip

So we enabled IP Restrictions for various profiles. One of our users uses the Google Sheets SF Add-On and cannot log in to SF when there is IP restrictions (even though they are on the correct IP network). I troubleshooted this by removing the IP Restrictions from their profile and once I did, the user is able to log in to SF on the Google Sheet SF Add-On.

The Add-on is Data connector for Salesforce:
https://gsuite.google.com/u/0/marketplace/app/data_connector_for_salesforce/857627895310?hl=en&pann=sheets_addon_widget

What is going on here? What is the work around so that we can keep the IP restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple fix using a few quick steps:

1. Reinstate the IP Restrictions on the User's Profile
2. Have the user attempt to OAuth the Data Connector for Salesforce through Google sheets (they should get an error, we want that)
3. Navigate to the User's page in Salesforce, and scroll down to "Login History", you should see something akin to the below:

[image]

4. Fetch the IP from the failed login attempt and whitelist that.

**Note: it's very likely that the IP you end up whitelisting right now isn't the only one that could / will be used by the Data Connector, so you may need to repeat this intermittently as they run into the issue again.

Comment: Thanks - that helps give me a better idea of what we're dealing with. Appreciate your time.